# Error while running Map reduce on Hadoop 2.6.0 on Windows

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I've setup a single node Hadoop 2.6.0 cluster on my Windows 8.1 using this tutorial - https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows.

All daemons are up and running. I'm able to access hdfs using `hadoop fs -ls /` but I've not loaded anything, so there is nothing to show up as of now.

But when I run a simple map reduce program, I get the below erorr :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCrc32.nativeComputeChunkedSumsByteArray(II[BI[BIILjava/lang/String;JZ)V
at org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCrc32.nativeComputeChunkedSumsByteArray(Native Method)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCrc32.calculateChunkedSumsByteArray(NativeCrc32.java:86)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.DataChecksum.calculateChunkedSums(DataChecksum.java:430)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.writeChecksumChunks(FSOutputSummer.java:202)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.flushBuffer(FSOutputSummer.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.flushBuffer(FSOutputSummer.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.close(ChecksumFileSystem.java:400)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.split.JobSplitWriter.createSplitFiles(JobSplitWriter.java:80)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:603)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:614)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:492)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1314)
at wordcount.Wordcount.main(Wordcount.java:62)
```

Error from `hadoop fs -put` command :

[image]

Any advise would be of great help.

Comment: UnsatisfiedLinkError... Is problematic http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html

Answer (score 4):

`org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCrc32.nativeComputeChunkedSumsByteArray` is part of [`hadoop.dll`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/native/src/org/apache/hadoop/util/NativeCrc32.c):

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_apache_hadoop_util_NativeCrc32_nativeComputeChunkedSumsByteArray
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,
    jint bytes_per_checksum, jint j_crc_type,
    jarray j_sums, jint sums_offset,
    jarray j_data, jint data_offset, jint data_len,
    jstring j_filename, jlong base_pos, jboolean verify)
{
  ...
```

Unsatisfied link would indicate that you did not deploy Hadoop.dll in %HADOOP_HOME%\bin or the process loaded a wrong dll from somewhere else. Make sure the correct dll is placed in %HADOOP_HOME%\bin, and make sure this is the one loaded (use [process explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx))

You should also see in the log the [`NativeCodeLoader`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/util/NativeCodeLoader.java) output:

```
 private static boolean nativeCodeLoaded = false;

  static {
    // Try to load native hadoop library and set fallback flag appropriately
    if(LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
      LOG.debug("Trying to load the custom-built native-hadoop library...");
    }
    try {
      System.loadLibrary("hadoop");
      LOG.debug("Loaded the native-hadoop library");
      nativeCodeLoaded = true;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      // Ignore failure to load
      if(LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOG.debug("Failed to load native-hadoop with error: " + t);
        LOG.debug("java.library.path=" +
            System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
      }
    }

    if (!nativeCodeLoaded) {
      LOG.warn("Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... " +
               "using builtin-java classes where applicable");
    }
```

Enable DEBUG level for this component and you should see `"Loaded the native-hadoop library"` (since your code acts as if the hadoop.dll was loaded). The most likely problem is that the wrong one is loaded because is found first in the PATH.

Comment: Thanks. It was loading correct hadoop.dll file but it has to be modifed to get everything working on Windows. Moreover, hadoop.dll should also be added to C:/Windows/System32. I got working with the help of this link - http://www.cnblogs.com/marost/p/4372778.html(Use Google translator to translate it to your native :) )

Comment: I am running hadoop using the .tar file from the mirror link and getting the same error. Can you tell me where to modify the code or how to resolve this error ? I am stuck with this for the past week. Thanks

Comment: @AppleBud check the link in my below comment. Would help for sure.

Answer (score 1):

hadoop.dll should also be added to C:/Windows/System32. I got it working with the help of this link - http://cnblogs.com/marost/p/4372778.html (Use an online translator to translate it to your native language)

Comment: This worked for me. Hence the plus one. This is also another side to the story, if the dll does exist in System32 and you still exprience this error, replace it with the dll from your hadoop bin.